# how to use Azure App Configuration in Angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-app-configuration

Is it possible to use Azure App config in Angular application? 
goal is to define Secrets and other strings in [Azure App Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview)

and use it in Angular application.

All the examples out there are for .Net

Comment: Don't use AppConfig for secrets. From [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/restoring-a-deleted-repository): "However, some types of data may be better suited to reside in other sources. For example, store secrets in Key Vault"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a npm package available for Azure App Confrig: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/app-configuration

Essentially, your code would have something like this:

```
const client = new AppConfigurationClient("<connection string>");

const setting = await client.getConfigurationSetting({
  key: "hello"
});

console.log("Retrieved value:", setting.value);
```

I would encourage you to strongly consider connecting to App Config on the server-side instead of client-side. Once you use a client-side the connection string for your App Config instance is essentially public for anyone to access, including values that you didn't intend them to have. It also allows them to make as many requests as they want until you rotate the keys, possibly inflating your Azure bill. If you've considered these issues and decided the risk is worth it, then the npm package and the examples in its docs should get you on the right path.

Comment: I was thinking about using a read-only access connectionstring but you are totally right about the possible Azure bill

Comment: It seems this is a chicken-and-egg problem.  The `new AppConfigurationClient(...)` presumably needs a different string for prod, stage and dev.  To obtain that string, you need configuration.  Face palm.  Am I wrong?